# Automapper child collection loses foreign key id while updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to map entity and it's child collection. First I retrieve entity and child collection from database:

```
public async Task<int> Update(EmailTemplateModel model, int id)
{
    var emailTemplate = _context.EmailTemplates.Include("EmailTemplateComponents").Include("Site").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    _mapper.Map(model, emailTemplate);

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

then I use mapper, but in this case I lose EmailTemplate link in EmailTemplateComponents and I get an error:

> "$id": "1",
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is
>   non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related
>   foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does
>   not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the
>   foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the
>   unrelated object must be deleted.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",

My entities are this:

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailTemplate : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AuthorDisplayName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual List<EmailTemplateComponent> EmailTemplateComponents { get; set; }

    //Site
    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SiteId")]
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class EmailTemplateComponent : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsTop { get; set; }
    public bool IsBottom { get; set; }
    public bool AlignRight { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    //Email template
    public int EmailTemplateId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmailTemplateId")]
    public virtual EmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

And mapping is this:

```
public class EmailTemplateProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<EmailTemplateModel, EmailTemplate>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorDisplayName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Author))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailTemplateComponents, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Components))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
                .IgnoreAllNonExisting()
                .IgnoreAllNonExistingSource();

            CreateMap<EmailTemplate, EmailTemplateModel> ()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Author, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.AuthorDisplayName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Components, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.EmailTemplateComponents))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
                .IgnoreAllNonExisting()
                .IgnoreAllNonExistingSource();

            CreateMap<EmailTemplateComponent, EmailTemplateComponentModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailTemplateId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.EmailTemplateId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.IsTop, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.IsTop))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.IsBottom, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.IsBottom))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Text, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Text))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
                .F

orMember(dest => dest.Url, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Url))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ImageUrl, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ImageUrl))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AlignRight, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.AlignRight))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailTemplate, opts => opts.UseDestinationValue())
                .IgnoreAllNonExisting()
                .IgnoreAllNonExistingSource()
                .ReverseMap();
        }
```

I can't seem to figure out why it is replacing the values in child collection with nulls?

Comment: You need [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) extension

Comment: Does this work with 4.2.1 version since I don’t have an option to update... legacy

Comment: Have no idea. But I don't see other solution (except manual synchronization which defeats the usage of AM) because `Map` simply replaces the target collection with brand new, which is causing EF to try disassociating the exiting child entities from their parent, hence the exception.